# redirect 301 some url apache + nginx

Tags: apache, .htaccess, nginx

please help me about this problem, I have problem with some url like

https://www.xxx.domain.com  now I have many xxx words the domain is in https and wild cart, but with this words after www. show message that the ssl not is valid for this url www.yyy.domain.com I use apache + nginx I not have found one solution
for redirect 301 or 410 url like www.word.domain.com

Please help me, thnaks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Dear Mike, Hi,  thnaks for you reply, please sorry, for confusion, I had in the past; subdomains, sub1 sub2 etc etc, this subdomain is now delete, I have note that google (where google found this subdomain it's a mistery) index https.//www.sub.domain.com not https://sub.domain.com now for https://sub.domain.com I have resolve to make 301 to https://sub.domain.com to https://www.domain.com but for https://www.sub.domain.com not have resolve in no way,